# messagebox.showinfo - вывести текст и переменную

Tags: python, tkinter

Не могу найти, как вывести в окно сначала текст, потом переменную: "Результат: ..."

Просто результат переменных выводит, а с текстом не получается.

```
def clicked():
    messagebox.showinfo("Результат", one.get() * two.get())
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью форматирования строк:

```
def clicked():
    res = "Результат: %.2f" % (one.get() * two.get())
    messagebox.showinfo("Результат", res)
```